# Re-using reference to an IReliableCollection

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Is it acceptable to re-use a reference to a `IReliableCollection` or should I request from `IReliableStateManager` every time I want to use it?

For example, if I have a dictionary that is widely used in my application, is it acceptable to retrieve it once in the `RunAsync` method and then pass this reference to any method that requires it, e.g:

```
protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _someCollection = StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<int, string>>(
        "SomeName");
}

public async Task DoSomething(int id, string message)
{
    _someClass.DoSomething(_someCollection, id, message);
}
```

And then use in a class like so:

```
public class SomeClass 
{
    public void DoSomething(IReliableDictionary<int, string> dict, int id, string msg)
    {
        using (ITransaction tx = StateManager.CreateTransaction()) 
        {
            await dict.AddAsync(tx, id, msg);
            await tx.CommitAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Or should I request from `IReliableStateManager` on each call, e.g,

```
public class SomeClass 
{
    public void DoSomething(int id, string msg)
    { 
        var dict = StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<int, string>>("SomeName");

        using (ITransaction tx = StateManager.CreateTransaction()) 
        {
            await dict.AddAsync(tx, id, msg);
            await tx.CommitAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Passing a reference seems to work fine from what I can tell but I'm not sure whether this would be considered bad practice and I can't find a definitive answer in the [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections-guidelines) or [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-work-with-reliable-collections)

Comment: I did ask that very same question, see https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/9713 for the answer

Comment: You can. but, It slows down the app. for ex, if you are doing bulk inserts/updates to SF and want to do a count, using the same reference, it gets stuck. I found other issues too. Better to avoid it.

Comment: @teeboy what do you mean by gets stuck? What sort of behavior do you see in this scenario?

Comment: It means, when I request a count of records using the "count" property while the bulk insert is happening, it does not return until bulk insert finished. That is why I don't use member vars for stroing dictionary references..also, queries were slower on reliable collection when using same reference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can.

You can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-notifications) to see how you can even receive notifications when new instance of `IReliableState` is added to `ReliableStateManager`.

You can also subscribe for events (if this is a dictionary).

Comment: You can. but, It slows down the app. for ex, if you are doing bulk inserts/updates to SF and want to do a count, using the same reference, it gets stuck. I found other issues too. Better to avoid it.

Comment: @teeboy it always depends on the use-case. The OP was asking about the possibility and there is a possibility.

Comment: Yes, but we also need to caution the OP about potential pitfalls when doing something that causes instability.

Comment: @teeboy did you had a chance to benchmark? I have tried this and from the glance I cannot see any issues. Can you describe the use case where you had issues in more details?

Comment: sure, have a complex key value reliable dictionary. ex: IReliableDictionary2<CustomerKey, CustomerValue>. Have customerkey correctly implement IComparable and IEquatable. get a reference to ReliableDictionary in a member variable. Do a bulk insert into the dicitonary and while the insert is happening, query your dictionary using the "same" reference you got earlier in member var and use "CreateEnumerableAsync(tx, o => predicate)". You will notice slowness in queries. [especially when mutiple clients query at the same time]. If you get a new reference everytime, this does not happen.